# WildFly - обновление на лету

Tags: java, wildfly, j2ee

Есть сервер на WildFly 8.2 содержащий кучу взаимодействующих компонент (EJB модули, сервлеты, веб-сервисы и т.д.). Сервер работает 24х7.
Для обновления приходится его останавливать, проводить обновление, потом запускать. Это конечно не долго, в среднем 10 минут в месяц не работает, но хотелось бы 100% uptime.

Есть ли какие-то стандартные средства J2EE или непосредственно WildFly для обновления компонент на лету? Или может быть отдельные библиотеки/фреймворки?

Стандартный redeploy не очень подходит, т.к. на сколько я понимаю не будет доступен отдельный компонент, пока старый уже деинсталлирован, а новый еще деплоится.

Можно самому написать что-то типа прокси-класса, который будет знать о двух версиях и плавно перенаправит с одной на другую. Вот тут как раз боюсь что велосипед изобретать буду.

З.Ы. Вариант с прокси/балансером перед двумя серверами пока не рассматривается, т.к. нужен будет еще один сервер, это крайний вариант.

Comment: Прокси/балансер можно установить и на один из серверов wildfly.  Кроме того сам wildfly может быть проксёй/балансером, чем и хвастается. А вообще для отказоустойчивости предполагается кластер. В wildfly организуется через domain-ы.

Comment: Можете попытаться использовать в качестве прокси nginx. В случае ошибки на перовом сервере он запомнит запрос и перенаправит на другой и выдаст пользователю нормальную страницу. На других проксях такую возможность не нашёл. Они сначала покажут станицу с ошибкой, потом только перейдут на рабочий сервер.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Варианты:

**1. Микросервисы**

итоговое приложение будет декомпозировано на [микросервисы](http://martinfowler.com/articles/microservices.html)

плюсы:

- свобода технологий
- намного легче поддерживать
- свобода подходов: оркестратор, хореограф и т.д.

минусы:

- чем больше микросервисов тем больше требуется контроля за ними. т.е. потребуется как минимум собственный мониторинг

**2. Миграция на [OSGi](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/OSGi)**

Например, на базе [Karaf](http://karaf.apache.org/) можно собрать приложение состоящие из бандлов. У OSGi используется подход оркестратора

плюсы:

- платформа OSGi предоставляет много плюшек прямо из коробки
- легче поддерживать, обновлять

минусы:

- выше порог вхождения для программистов

---

оба подхода могут потребовать существенные трудозатраты программистов (в зависимости от текущей архитектуры проекта)